# Storyboards, segues, settext not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have a storyboard hosting a number of Viewcontrollers ( VC's ).
in one of those VC's, I have a button that when clicked pushes another VC on the navigationcontroller. Now I achieve this in the storyboard using a segue.
Now in the pushed VC I am supposed to change the text of some buttons based on some data I have, 
In the viewdidload method I go and try to edit the text like so

```
NSString *value1 = //Load from some place;
NSString *value2 = //Load from some place;
NSString *value3 = //Load from some place;

[self.btn1.titleLabel setText:value1];
[self.btn2.titleLabel setText:value2];
[self.btn3.titleLabel setText:value3];
```

I am doing this in the viewdidload method of the pushed VC. The problem is that those buttons never update with the text?? 
I did set a breakpoint and the buttons are there they are not nil,  also I did notice that this method never gets called

```
  - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
```

Comment: put NSLog in viewDidLoad and check if value1 is not nil

Comment: If you are going to post the question again, don't write the same exact thing. It will get closed again. Please state where the above code is (in which method) and where you call the NSLog (in which method)

Comment: I think I'd need to know a little more about your code to give a proper response, but try putting that first block of code in the viewDidAppear method instead of viewDidLoad and see whether it works then...because if the view's already been loaded in the past and hasn't been unloaded, it won't call viewDidLoad again, but it will call viewDidAppear every time it appears.

Comment: And I agree with both visualication and Wyatt's answers… I've never set a button in the way you're doing it though by using "titleLabel", but I know Wyatt's answer works in setting button labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
[self.btn1 setTitle:value1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

try the same in viewWillAppear method of your vc